# How do you call a stored procedure with activerecord?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

The only relevant answer to these kind of questions was [this](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/4/topics/777), but it doesn't help.
Any push in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is your general problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured it out how to do it.

```
$result = User::find_by_sql("CALL procedure(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

You can use any model there.
My procedure ends up doing a select, but I guess that find_by_sql can be used for anything.